# Open file on tablet from smartphone

Tags: file-system, file-management, file-sharing

How do I view the files on my tablet from my phone? Do I have to connect wirelessly? I am working on a translation and would like to see the original on one tablet and the file I'm working on on the smartphone or other tablet.

Do I need an app or is this service part of the OS? I would like to just use Bluetooth.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to see from phone the `files` on tablet or some translation app running on tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an FTP server on your tablet, then connect your phone via a browser to your tablet.

Download an [FTP server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ftp%20server&c=apps) via Google Play Store. I use [FTP Server - Multiple FTP users](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.ftpserver) for the demonstration below, however you are free to use other apps of your liking.

1. Enable WiFi hotspot on your tablet. Connect the phone to the WIFI hostpot.
2. Open the app, click on `User management`. Create a new user. Add the name, username and password. Click `Add new`, select the path of files that can be accessed via FTP (SD card, internal storage, etc). Click `OK`. (If you don't want to create a user, you can just enable `Anonymous` and add the path to your files).

   [image: IMG:]
3. Click `Home`, then `Start`.

   [image: IMG:]
4. Open a browser on your phone, enter the URL of the FTP server as seen on the image above. You will then be able to view the files stored on the tablet from the phone.

   [image: IMG:]